# Ubuntu Server - no internet connection

Tags: server, internet, connection

I've installed Ubuntu Server on server machine with two network cards, whereas only one of them is wired to local network. When I type:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

I get following:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto p2p1
iface p2p1 inet static
    address 161.53.68.226
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 161.53.68.0
    broadcast 161.53.68.255
    gateway 161.53.68.1
```

When I try:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

I get "Destination Host Unreachable". How do I fix this?

P.S. Maybe this can also help. When I type

```
route -n
```

I get:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway    Genmask    Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

i.e. routing table is empty.

Thanks!

Best,
Marko.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

> sudo ifdown p2p1;sudo ifup p2p1

or adding your gateway manually (this won't be preserved after reboot):

> sudo ip r add default via 161.53.68.1 dev p2p1

Anyway, you can remove network and broadcast from interfaces, those are automatically resolved. Just put address,netmask and gateway.

Comment: I did what you've suggested, and I still get "Destination Host Unreachable" on ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: Can you post the output of `ip address` please?